Cors Error when connecting react app to spring boot 3.2.5 and spring security 6.2.4
Spring Boot: 3.2.5
Spring security: 6.2.4
In the below code:
@Bean
  JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    RestOperations rest = builder.setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(TIME_OUT))
        .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(TIME_OUT))
        .build();

    NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(keysSet).restOperations(rest).build();

    OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator = new AudienceValidator(audience);
    OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer);
    OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer,
        audienceValidator);

    jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);

    return jwtDecoder;
  }

  @Bean
  JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter converter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    converter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("permissions");
    converter.setAuthorityPrefix("");

    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    jwtConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(converter);
    return jwtConverter;
  }

  @Bean
  @Order(3)
  SecurityFilterChain oauthSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    log.info("within oauth");
    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()));
    http.securityMatcher(ADMIN_API_PATH);
    http.headers(headers -> headers
            .httpStrictTransportSecurity(hsts -> hsts
            .includeSubDomains(true)
            .maxAgeInSeconds(31536000)));
    log.info("path matched with oauth: {}", ADMIN_API_PATH);
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth.requestMatchers(ADMIN_API_PATH).authenticated())
        .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter())));
    return http.build();
  }

  @Bean
  @Order(1)
  SecurityFilterChain xauthSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // log.info("within xauth");
    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()));
    http.securityMatcher(X_AUTH_API);
    http.headers(headers -> headers
            .httpStrictTransportSecurity(hsts -> hsts
            .includeSubDomains(true)
            .maxAgeInSeconds(31536000)));
    log.info("path matched with xauth: {}", X_AUTH_API);

    CoreAuthFilter coreAuthFilter = new CoreAuthFilter(PRINCIPAL_REQUEST_HEADER);
    coreAuthFilter.setAuthenticationManager(getXAuthManager());
    http.authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth.requestMatchers(X_AUTH_API).authenticated())
            .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .addFilter(coreAuthFilter);
    return http.build();
  }

  @Bean
  WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return (web) -> web
        .ignoring()
        .requestMatchers(AUTH_WEB);
  }

  @Bean
  CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();

    config.setAllowedOriginPatterns(CORS_ALLOWED_DOMAINS);
    config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return source;
  }

  @Bean
  @Order(2)
  SecurityFilterChain jwtSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    // log.info("within jwt");
    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()));
    http.headers(headers -> headers
            .httpStrictTransportSecurity(hsts -> hsts
            .includeSubDomains(true)
            .maxAgeInSeconds(31536000)));
    Arrays.stream(AUTH_WHITELIST).forEach((k) -> {
      log.info("Whitelisted URL {}", k);
    });

    http.securityMatcher(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher(API_PATH));
    log.info("path matched with jwt: {}", API_PATH);

    http.authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth.requestMatchers(API_PATH).authenticated())
            .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .addFilterBefore(new JwtFilter(tokenProvider), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    return http.build();
  }

When trying to access whitelisted APIs in AUTH_WEB, ex: /request-login
I am getting cors error from react app.
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5001/api/v1/request-login' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
But when trying to access from postman, it is working.
Not sure what I am doing wrong.
Could someone fix it?
Tried:
.requestMatchers(AUTH_WEB).permitAll() instead of
No luck
